# angular 4 [selected] is displaying blank option rather than the chosen option

Tags: angular

hey guys I have the following code in my angular:

```
 <select class="form-control" required formControlName="validation">                         
    <option *ngFor="let option of rtoRpoReq; let i = index" [ngValue]=option [selected]="option.selected" [disabled]="option.disabled" > {{option.option}} </option>
 </select>
```

and the array of objects I'm looping through is the following:

```
{ "option": "question", "disabled": true, "selected": true },
{ "option": "option1", "formula": x },
{ "option": "option2", "formula": y },
{ "option": "option3", "formula": z }
```

my formControl looks like this:

```
    this.form = new FormGroup({
        validation: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    })
```

The problem is that I wish to display the first option as a placeholder, instead the box will be blank until I select one of the other options. Has anyone any idea how I could fix this?
Cheers

Comment: The source of truth, in Angular, is the model. So if your select is bound to a component field of to a form control, the option that is selected is the one having the same value ss that component field or form control. Don't use selected.

Comment: @JBNizet what would you suggest then?

Comment: To initialize the component field or the form control bound to the select with the value that you want selected. If you posted the relevant code, I could help you achieve that.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly. My guess was to do something like  (in my formBuilder)          myquestion: new FormControl('myObj[0].selected,Validators.required)

Comment: If you posted the relevant code, I could help. Post the relevant code.

Comment: hope that is enough dude

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should make your HTML valid, by adding double quotes around your attributes. You can also remove the useless index variable, and the useless selected attribute:

```
<select class="form-control" required formControlName="validation">                         
  <option *ngFor="let option of rtoRpoReq" [ngValue]="option" [disabled]="option.disabled">{{option.option}}</option>
</select>
```

Now, as you can see, the above select is bound to the form control named `validation`. So, the option that is selected is the option whose value is the value of the form control named `validation`.

Each option is associated to an element of the array `rtoRpoReq`, and the value of the option is the element of the array itself:

```
*ngFor="let option of rtoRpoReq" [ngValue]="option"
```

So, if you want the first element to be selected (for example), then the first element of the `rtoRpoReq` array must be the value of the form control.

So the form constrol should be created using:

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
    validation: new FormControl(this.rtoRpoReq[0], Validators.required),
});
```

If you want the third option to be the selected one, then use

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
    validation: new FormControl(this.rtoRpoReq[2], Validators.required),
});
```

If you want to programmatically change the selected value, then use

```
this.form.get('validation').value = this.rtoRpoReq[someIndex];
```

Comment: that's cool, it displays the option now. Problem is that now makes the form valid. Is there anyway of making it unvalid unless clicked an option?

Comment: If you don't want the first option to be a valid one, then it shouldn't be in your array, and nothing should be selected. Just add an option with an empty value in your template, and use an empty string as the value of your form group. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5efvwy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: great, thank you very much mate, that should have been more obvious